# How to force self-hosted Wordpress to allow permissions?

Tags: wordpress

I have a *self-hosted* Wordpress. And it is denying permission to access `export.php` even though I *am* set as Administrator. **Export** does not appear in the dashboard menu as expected either.

In wp_usermeta is:

```
wp_user_level = 10
wp_user_capabilities = a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}
...and I tried: a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}
```

How can I force permission even temporarily modifying any permission checks in export.php so as to be able to export?

(Using latest Wordpress version 3.8.1.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out the following 2 lines temporarily to bypass permissions:

```
if ( !current_user_can('export') )
    wp_die(__('You do not have sufficient permissions to export the content of this site.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the WordPress **capabilitys** (https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities)

```
 $administrator = get_role('administrator');
 if($administrator) {
      // Remove "Export" from admin's
      $administrator->remove_cap('export');
 }
```

If you want to add export permissions to other roles, than add these as follow:

```
 $subscriber = get_role('subscriber');
 if($subscriber) {
      // Add"Export" for subscriber's
      $subscriber->add_cap('export');
 }
```

As default, admins have the privilege to manage the export functions. But i think a plugin and/or theme from you will be remove the cap from admins.

Comment: Hi, I want to ADD export to Administrator (it should have it but it doesn't or is not recognizing it?), or force export.php to ignore permissions, with only one goal -> being able to export. I've tried disabling each plugin one by one with no change. I am the one and only user and administrator.